# Add Sabnzbd to a subdomain of a website

Tags: windows-home-server, domain-name, subdomain, usenet

I have a Windows Home Server 2011 set up that runs my various Usenet/Torrent program webUIs. What I'd like to know is whether or not I can use a domain name to allow me to access them when I am away from home. My ISP doesn't hand out static IP addresses, but they do have them fixed so they only ever change if something drastic changes.

I imagine it would be something like: www.example.com/sabnzbd/ or www.sabnzbd.example.com.

Is this possible, and if it is what do I need to learn or research in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at services like [No-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/personal/) (this one is free). You can register a sub-domain there fore free, and keep it dynamically linked to your home IP address.
To do so, you have to run the [free client software](http://www.no-ip.com/downloads.php?page=win) that they are providing on the machine you want to be linked with the sub-domain you have registered.

Comment: How do I then go about having it linked to the internal IP of my webUI? For example: http://192.168.1.1:8000.

Comment: I updated my answer to bring some more precisions. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: It answered it perfectly. I already had a No-IP account from another experiment, but completely forgot about it. I could use a paid domain with this service, yes?

Comment: Definitely. And if you're ready to pay, you can also look at other services, like DynDNS for instance, and probably a lot of others, but for your simple case I think the free service is enough.

Comment: Okay, one last question. Typing in my *.no-ip.org address takes me directly to my routers admin login page. How do I prevent this, or redirect it to something else?

Comment: Yes. You need either to redirect (through the router) port 80 to your locale machine if you have a webserver you want to access on it, or to change the port on which your web interface works (however it's not possible with all routers). On some routers, you also have the option to either block the web interface from the WAN, or to protect it with a login/password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5955/discussion-between-michael-frank-and-m4573r)